# how to make 2 dropdown menus in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

A dropdown menu that contains all invoice IDs.
B dropdown menu that is populated with all item descriptions.
FOLLOWING is my code, only one dropdown menu shows, I DO not know how to show both of them.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>3-invoice-item.php</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Select invoice_id and item_description and enter quantity:</h3>
      <form method="post" action="new 4.php">
        <div><label for="invoice">invoice_id </label><select name="invoice"><?php
          include "config.php";
          $c = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
          $query = "SELECT invoice_id
                      from invoice";
          $results = mysqli_query($c, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($c));
          while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            echo "<option>" . $result['invoice_id'] . "</option>";
          }

         $query = "SELECT  item_description
                   from item";
          $results = mysqli_query($c, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($c));
          while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
            echo "<option>" . $result['invoice_id'] . "</option>";
          }        
          mysqli_free_result($results);
          mysqli_close($c);
        ?></select></div>
         <div><label for="quantity">quantity: </label><input type="text" name="quantity"></div>
        <div><input type="submit" name="submit"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I see, you have only one <select> tag, so maybe that's why the second dropdown isn't showing. it is simply not there

Answer (score 0):

There's no code to create the second dropdown. Try adding this just after your first while loop ends.

```
echo "</select>";
echo "<select name='my_dropdown'>";
```

Comment: If you view the source of the page, what does the HTML look like where you'd expect the dropdown to appear?